# What is the local ring of the sheaf of regular functions with respect a component T

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, localization

I'm studying the theory of abelian coverings of varieties.

Let $\mathcal{O}_X$ be the sheaf of regular functions of a varieties $X$ and let $T$  be a closed subset of $X$. What means the symbol $\mathcal{O}_{X,T}$?

At the beginning I thunk that could be the localization of the ring $\mathcal{O}_X$ with respect the multiplicative subset $X\setminus\mathfrak{M}$ where $\mathfrak{M}$ is the prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_X$ of the regular functions that vanishing on $\mathfrak{M}$,  but the problem is that $\mathfrak{M}$ is not always a prime ideal, right?

Moreover, if $T$ is an hypersuface of $X$, then $M$ is a principal ideal generated by an entire regular function $f$, right?  So we have that $\mathfrak{M}/\mathfrak{M}^2$  is a $\mathcal{O}_{X,T}/\mathfrak{M}$-vector space?

Comment: Why is $S$  a multiplicative set? I'm working on an algebraically closed field with positive characteristic.

Comment: Let me make it clearer : at first there is $O_X(U)$ the ring of rational functions on $X$ regular on $U$ for each $U$ open, for $T\subset U$ there are two rings : the ring of functions regular on an open containing $T$ (ie. with denominator non-vanishing at any point of $T$), and the ring of functions regular on some open containing a dense subset of $T$ (ie. with denominator not vanishing everywhere on any irreducible component of $T$), for $T$ irreducible the quotient of the latter by the functions vanishing on the whole of $T$ is a field.

Comment: The latter has finitely many prime (and maximal) ideals, one for each irreducible component $T_j$ of $T$ : the ideal of functions regular and vanishing on a dense subset of $T_j$.